# Interviewers asking about specific companies where I was consulting

Tags: interviewing

I have been consulting for a few firms over the last few years specializing in a large software platform. When interviewing at other consulting firms, I have always used generalized answers as to where specifically I have worked, e.g. 'a large university' as opposed to 'Notre Dame'. I use the same technique on my resume. Now I have started interviewing with the manufacturer of the product in question and have had a couple questions regarding the specifics of the clients. I would assume it is so they could check how well the project was implemented or to go directly to their internal resources for additional information.

In this scenario should I divulge the this information or try to remain giving generic answers? It does not appear at face value to conflict with my NDA.

Comment: What sort of questions about your past clients have they asked, for example?

Comment: "It does not appear at face value to conflict with my NDA." So why are you asking us?

Answer (score 7):

> In this scenario should I divulge the this information or try to remain giving generic answers? It does not appear at face value to conflict with my NDA.

I asked in comments for clarification regarding *what specific* information/questions are they asking to better help you.

Meanwhile, if the questions do not seems to conflict with your NDAs and are about things like *"who was your last client?"* then it would seem harmless to disclose that information (unless the NDA prohibits you to disclosing them as clients).

Giving generic answers during interviews may raise some flags as to why you don't want to disclose such (harmless) information. If they ask you something that conflicts with your NDA you should be honest and say *"I'm sorry, but the specifics to that would conflict with my NDA"*. That would be preferred versus being vague or avoiding the question.

Answer (score 3):

> It does not appear at face value to conflict with my NDA.

Than it's fine. As long as you are not violating any confidentially agreement with your existing clients (or your employer, if you have one) I see no problem here. The vendor already knows the client is using the product and vice versa.

Chances are your hiring manager may reach out to the client and ask them about you or at least ping their internal sales rep or support engineer for the client how things are going. If you are ok with that, than I see no issue with that. Let your performance speak for you.

Answer (score 2):

If your NDA does not expressly restrict you from discussing the names of the businesses for whom you have consulted and you are comfortable sharing that information, it is typically prudent to offer specific responses when requested by possible employers. More thorough information about the clientele with whom you've worked will assist you illustrate your experience and the value you can offer to the new organisation. It might also help you create trust with the interviewer by being open and honest about your experience.